# jQuery not passing table markup from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a script for my mobile-freindly site so when the user scrolls to the bottom off my page it automatically loads the next part.

How-ever I'm having some issues with jQuery.

When this is the code:

```js
$('#Table tbody tr:last').after("<tr><td>Yes</td><td>No</td></tr>");
```

It adds the rows perfectly fine. This is the full function:

```
function AddMoreContent(){
console.log('Get more');
jQuery.post( "ajax.php", { file: 'loadMore.php',checkValue: CheckValue, time: time }, function( data ) {
    $('#Table tbody tr:last').after(data);

    LoadingMore = false;
});
```

}

The result from console.log of the data var is:

```
<tr>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td><p><strong>Name</strong><br/>Desc</p></td>
</tr>
```

But when looking with inspector, it seems like jQuery removes all the `tr` and `td` tags.

I read somewhere that jQuery generally dont like broken html, but it confuses me as it works fine if I type it in manually.

Thanks.

Comment: Might not solve the issue though .. But why not just `.append()` ?

Comment: Tried this, still same issue.

Comment: Don't assume everything you see in the inspector is true. It often does not refresh and does not show all the content there is on your page.

Comment: Okay, this seems random. Just went f-this and continued working on the loadMore file, and now it works flawlessly.

Comment: It seems, that a <head/> tag sneaks into the data reply, for no apparent reason. `data = data.replace('<head/>', '');` seems like a good temp fix.